# I get the RangeError (index): Invalid value: valid value range is empty:0

Tags: flutter

I have an API with two json.decode the List alts can receive null, but how is the solution for it?
I tried:

```
Center(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: data != null ? data.length : 0,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                              Map data = snapshot.data[index];
                                 if (data['alts'] != null) {
                                alts = json.decode(data['alts']);

                                alts.forEach((element) {
                                  print(element);
                                });
                              }
```

But i receive:RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: Which line is the error for? And what does your json data look like? please add more code that includes the original snapshot object as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing data before using it for itemCount

```
                    ...
                    Map data = snapshot.data[index];
                    ....
                    Center(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: data != null ? data.length : 0,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                                 if (data['alts'] != null) {
                                alts = json.decode(data['alts']);

                                alts.forEach((element) {
                                  print(element);
                                });
                              }
```